# Our Universe, but with a parallel component that is somehow connected to every location

Tags: science-based, physics, universe, spacetime-dimensions

I am looking to have a visual diagram that shows the structure of our physical Universe (I mean the physically recognized 3 dimensions) but with an additional sort of dimension(?) tacked on it.

This "dimension" would have the following characteristics:
1. electromagnetic radiation in our Universe would have some component(s) that are also visible in this additional "dimension"
2. the dimension could connect any two locations in our physical Universe so that those two locations are temporarily the same (allowing things space travel without space flight, teleportation, and access to closed containers)

(In this case there would be some villains who have somehow gained the knowledge of how to open these portals using electromagnetism.)

How could this kind of "Universe+" structure be drawn diagrammatically?

Comment: I'm not really sure this question can be answered as is. If we are to assume that you are only interested in the part of the EM spectrum that is visible to humans, then (metaphorically) why would the Universe care about humans? It feels like you could make this environment visually appear any way you like, because there is nothing even remotely like it in our world.

Comment: I tried to come to terms with which close reason best describes my feelings as to why this is close-worthy, and I'm not sure I picked the best one, but if you want us to tell you what it would look like, you have to at the very least be far more specific about how our world and this additional dimension interact with each other.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, apologies but I think my question was not really clear. I am not looking for a (verbal or otherwise) description of its appearance but more like a visual diagram of the structure of the universe. I have now updated the question.

Comment: Recently I read of an experiment in which it was established that quantum entanglement effects must travel at least 10,000 times faster than light. No upper boundary has been established. My thought was, maybe there is an undiscovered dimension in spacetime where all components of the universe are still connected the way they were in the very first instant of the beginning of the universe.

Comment: Okay, this really makes no sense. You want a fourth "dimension" for a three dimensional world that has to do with EM radiation and can let people teleport and reach into closed containers?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon isn't the base question "how do you draw a 4th dimension onto a map, given that the 4th dimension connects certain points in 3D space of the universe"? If you ignore the EM radiation stuff (which is just story fluff) the question makes sense to me...

Comment: @Aify Put it that way then what is to say one way is better than anther? Then it fits my close reason as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon You didn't say anything about primarily opinion based, and the noted close reason is "unclear what you're asking". I don't see this question as too opinion based since IMO there's unlikely to be more than 1 or 2 valid answers that would work consistently. The best answer could be decided through checking which method of mapping is the easiest to read and most consistent, or some other criteria the OP could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Itll have to look like that of which your mind becomes a dimension of. Your thoughts, imagination your belief in the purpose of what you are attempting becomes that reality reguardless of where you maybe, The mind can still see when eyes dont see cant see are not looking to  see was not in position to see but in the mind you will always see a scene a site a visual a picture an image and more and with just that you could be anywhere you  are seeing yourself at and position yourself to be. A trust in travel. Dimension. And in universe itll be like living in your supreme dreams..

You had a thought, a question, wonder for thoughts and or answer  i had a thought and wanted to share

Comment: Thanks Ayez for your answer and my apologies as I think my question was not really clear. I am not looking for a (verbal or otherwise) description of the appearance of this universe but more like some kind of a visual diagram showing the structure. I have now updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this question correctly, plotting this universe structure onto a  map is a simple matter of plotting points onto 3D space normally, and then adding a 4th dimensional point to each of those points for the portals.

For example:

Points are normally plotted (x,y,z), where x, y and z are the 3D planes of existence.

In your universe, you simply have each point labeled (x, y, z, d), where d represents the point in the other dimension. How does this help plot the portal locations though? Well, since the portal locations are stated to be "temporarily the same", the point (x1, y1, z1, d1) would be a different point in the **physical** universe than the point (x2, y2, z2, d1), but the same point in the alternate dimension - the d1 point. So someone standing at (15, 1, 3, 1) could theoretically open up a portal to a point (3233, 23231, 545, 1), assuming you wanted those 2 points in the universe to have a connection.

[image: 4D map]

Imagine that this picture is one of your maps, perhaps a map of a quadrant of space. In the center of this map is the "origin" of your map, so perhaps a star or something. Note that the x y z coordinates are relative to the origin of the map, (numbers not to scale in this picture) but the 4th number (the "d" number) comes in pairs. This can be used to signify how the different points connect to eachother. So in this map, a person standing on either of the white points can "move" through the portal to get to the other point", and red to red, blue to blue, etc.

In my picture, I used color to differentiate the points because it makes it a bit easier to understand, but of course, you could use only color to differentiate between portals; but then you'd quickly run out of colors that you can discern from the visible eye. This method allows you to link an infinite number of points in the universe together simply by using the same "d" number on the points.